# How do I open and use phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed MySQL through terminal and also installed MySQL client through software center. Now, how can I open the MySQL client. I have to create, edit, database and tables in it.

How can I open `phpmyadmin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phpmyadmin` is **not** included in `mysql-client`, you need to install it manually.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

When the installation is done, you can open `phpmyadmin` in your browser at this address : http://localhost/phpmyadmin.

---

If you still have a 404 error run :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html
```

And try again.

Comment: i installed it . but it still shows blank page. i mean 404 page not found error

Comment: when  i open http://localhost/ it works fine. it shows " it works". but i cant open phpmyadmin

Comment: During the phpmyadmin installation, are you sure you checked `apache2` at this screen ? : http://i.stack.imgur.com/BWvTz.png

Comment: Yes I did it. I checked apache2.   First installed  apache2 and than php5 and followed by mysql and it's client than phpmyadmin.  Am I right? .  Anyhting I missed.?

Comment: Let me remove and install again. Thanks for your answers. I am accepting it.  But I didn't get solution for my problem

Comment: Wait, please run : `sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql`, then  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

Comment: I tried this too. It shows everything right way  and i already configured it apache2.

Comment: Now try : `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html`

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. Thanks a lot. It worked.  I don't have reputation to vote it up.

Comment: Great! No problem, you accepted it ;)